# Why do commands listed in the .sh script are not executed while manual typing works?

Tags: bash

I have the OCI runtime bundle which I run with **Dobby** - RDK utility (use **crun** under the hood). I have specified my custom **entrypoint.sh** script to be run on startup in `config.json`:

```
"process": {         
        "args": [             
            "sh",               
            "entrypoint.sh"
        ],             
        "cwd": "/",
        "env": [            
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "TERM=xterm"
        ],                  
        "terminal": true,             
        "user": {       
            "uid": 0,    
            "gid": 0     
        }
```

entrypoint.sh script itself:

```
#!/bin/sh

while true;
do
sleep 1
lighttpd -v >> lighttpd_version.txt
which lighttpd >> lighttpd_which.txt
lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
done
```

Bundle structure is OK:

```
/path_to_bundle
   /config.json
   /rootfs
      ...
```

My bundle is based on Alpine image for arm architecture (I have added some additional tools needed).

Having my container running with the `DobbyTool start mycontainer /path_to_bundle` command, I use `nsenter -m -u -i -n -p -t $INIT_CONTAINER_PROCESS_PID` to "step into" the container.

While the script itself is definetely being executed (I track sleep processes via ps - each time with different pid, `which lighttpd >> lighttpd_which.txt` command also works OK) but commands like `lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` or `lighttpd -v >> lighttpd_version.txt` doesn`t execute.

**Results of execution:**

```
which lighttpd >> lighttpd_which.txt # shows valid path to command at /usr/sbin/lighttpd

lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf # neither echoing its result nor getting $! doesn`t work - emptiness

lighttpd -v >> lighttpd_version.txt # doesn`t even create a specified output file
```

When I manually run `lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` or the **entrypoint.sh** script inside the running container everything is working fine - server is up and running.

**Edit:**

I have also tried to run the script in container as follows:

```
sh -x entrypoint.sh 2> debug.txt
```

It simply doesn`t create that **debug.txt** file. Manual typing works OK...

Comment: Why do you think `lighttpd -f ` isn't running? It sounds like it *is* running, as the foreground process, and blocking the rest of the script from executing until it exits/

Comment: Bacause I can't see it via ps. Furthemore I can see constantly changing pid for sleep process. Lastly it is run in background by default - I didn't use -D option: `-D  don't go to background (default: go to background)`

Comment: By the way, I have used crun directly and spotted this error with the lighttpd: `server.c.1391) setgid(): Operation not permitted`. It seems like that could be an issue. However running `lighttpd -v` works fine despite not beeing executed in script...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the used wrapper to run containers **Dobby** have been redirecting all the command`s output somewhere. On the other hand, running the same thing(runtime bundle) with **crun** shed some light on the problem - I have got a message indicating insufficient rights given to the process (specifically no rights to change uid or pid) - some internal things happening in the lighttpd utility. So adding some additional capabilities (**CAP_SETGID** and **CAP_SETUID** for my specific error) under the same name section in the "process" object in config.json has fixed the problem.

So the thing I will do next time while debugging similar problems - use as deep tools available as I can to detect possible errors on some underlying levels.

Answer (score 0):

Try substitute `lighttpd` in your script with the full path to it, i.e. what prints when you run `which lighttpd`.
For example, if `which lighttpd` prints `/usr/sbin/lighttpd`, your script should be like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

while true;
do
sleep 1
/usr/sbin/lighttpd -v >> lighttpd_version.txt
which lighttpd >> lighttpd_which.txt
/usr/sbin/lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
done
```

Comment: Thanks for a reply. Unfortunately, I have been trying to do so - no results. It also shouldn't be a problem as needed paths are listed in **env object** in **config.json**. By the way, sometimes I can catch that **lighttpd** command up and running (but that happens like one in a blue moon) but I can't reproduce it. Basically I change nothing - that is why...